# How to handle several axios request successfully when some of them are failed

Tags: express, axios, es6-promise

Suppose I have a express server which need to connect(send data) several express server. Like this:

```js
app.post('/events', async (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;
  events.push(event)

  try {
    console.log(`event received ${event.type}`)
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/events', event);
    console.log('event sent to 4000')
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4001/events', event);
    console.log('event sent to 4001')
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4002/events', event); //<-- server stopped hence go catch block
    console.log('event sent to 4002')
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4003/events', event); //<-- never come here
    console.log('event sent to 4003')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  res.send({ status: 'OK' });
});
```

And some reason one of the express server is stopped. Let the server which is running on port `4002` is stopped but then I can't post data to the server running port on `4003`. Is there any way to handle the `ECONNREFUSED` error which was caught by the catch block as well as send the data to the server running port on `4003`?

Comment: Use `try/catch` to catch rejections from the promise you `await`.  I don't see any reason these need to be sequenced one after another either with `await`.  You can probably get rid of the `await`, put all the promises in an array and use `Promise.allSettled()` to know when they are all done and then examine which ones succeeded and which ones didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jfriend00 suggested you can use `Promise.allSettled()`,

```js
const promise1 = axios.post('http://localhost:4000/events', event)
  const promise2 = axios.post('http://localhost:4001/events', event)
  const promise3 = axios.post('http://localhost:4002/events', event)
  const promise4 = axios.post('http://localhost:4003/events', event)
  const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4];

  Promise.allSettled(promises).
    then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));
```

Instead of `try/catch`.